# How to use static variables efficiently?

Tags: java, android, performance, static

I like to know some basic stuffs

I am developing an android application and thus it lead me to memory management issues. 
Recently watched  a video related to memory management by google I found that using a static variable in an activity causes memory leaks even in orientation change of activity as it keeps references to other objects in the activity,The man in video said that using **static variable with the help of a static method will solve the issue, I like to know how a static method will solve the issue ?**

I like to know the very best way to use static variable in my application for example I have a global class in which I stores some static variables as its name indicates these values will assessed  and modified  by different activities,
As an example I have a static variable WIDTH and currently  update it like this

`Global.WIDTH = 12`

or get it like **`int width = Global.WIDTH`**
from different activites, is this is a correct method ,or do i have to use a static method to get the width like **`int width = Global.getWidth();`,then what's the difference between both of these** , what is the best way to do this,

**what are other important things we have to keep in mind when dealing with static variables ?**

Thank you all and sorry for the long description ...

Comment: Use `static` when the field/method must belong to the class and not to any object reference. If used in `Activity`s, I would recommend using `static final` to declare the field as a constant instead of having a plain wild `static` field there.

Comment: Thank you for quick response .. I cant declare it as final because its value will change as per device based on a calculation

Comment: You can declare it as `static final` and define the values in a `static{ }` method. Note that these values even if being *dynamic*, they *should* be loaded only once in your application start, not anytime of the application. If you want to have different width and height for landscape visualization, add two more fields instead of recalculating the values.

Comment: Hmm.. thank you tha'ts a great Idea. and one more thing do any differences on keeping references  when we access these value directly from fields and using static methods

Comment: Any `static` fields will remain in memory until the class is unloaded, so I would say to only refer to a `static` object reference as local variable or parameter of your method, do not use it to directly fill a field of one of your classes.

Comment: you mean its not bad to use/refer them in local variables (such as inside a method) and not assign them to any fields inside the class,if assigned it will remain until the class get destroyed, otherwise only in the methods life cycle. and no difference in accessing a static filed directly or accessing it using a static method .Am i right ?

Comment: @RenjithKN I also watched the video and i am also facing same problem.. If you find something usefull please add it.I need the solution badly

Comment: me too, will try the suggestions I got from this comments and answers,hopes  will make changes in perfomance

Answer (score 1):

Static variables can cause memory leaks because they'll never go out of scope, but if you only have a few primitives such as int or long then you won't have a problem.

You need to be careful if you start referring to objects in static variables, especially collections. If a collection never goes out of scope, neither do any of the objects contained within it, and neither do any of the objects they refer to, so there's a chance that the collection will continue to grow and use up more and memory.

The variable in your question, presumably an int, will be OK though.

Comment: Thank you Nick for the answer, I used the int for an example, I like to know do there any difference between the usage of static fields and static methods

Comment: I can't think of any memory implications with using static methods. The only difference between Global.width and Global.getWidth() is that the method will allow you to calculate the value when called. Any variables declared and used in the method will not cause a memory leak because they go out of scope as soon as the method ends.